# Why isn't there a hydrogen bond present between the oxygen atom and hydrogen atom of adjacent alcohol groups?

Tags: organic-chemistry, hydrogen-bond

[image: Glycerol- Three adjacent "OH" groups.]

*I know that there is inter-molecular hydrogen bonding between the molecules of glycerol.

*What makes the adjacent alcohol groups behave differently towards each other as compared to when they interact through separate molecules?

*(additional question) - How many Carbon-Carbon single bonds worth do hydrogen bonds persist?

Comment: The hydrogen and oxygen are not close enough. If they made a 6-membered ring with the h-bond they might be, but here the best they can do is a 5-member ring and that is too far.

Comment: @matt_black 5-membered rings are perfectly fine for h-bonds and OP is spawning nonsense here.

Comment: Do the adjacent "OH' have hydrogen bonds between each other?

Comment: @Mithoron Do you have an example? Given that a 'strong' hydrogen bond should have a ~180° angle around H, I wouldn't expect five membered rings to be anywhere large enough.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン What do you mean by " 'strong' hydrogen bond should have a ~180° angle around H"

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Well, I don't say they're strong, still https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2210271X1000767X

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/31390/why-does-the-gauche-conformation-of-ethane-1-2-diol-show-hydrogen-bonding

Comment: @mithoron indeed, you're absolutely right. It is not strong, bit it would be wrong to disregard this interaction. // With that statement I meant that the hydrogen in the hydrogen bond should ideally be linearly coordinated, i.e. the bond angle $\angle\ce{O-H...O}\approx 180^\circ$.